# Minimize prompt dialog on button click - Bot framework C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, bots

I am a learner using Bot-framework. I am trying to find a way to minimize a prompt dialog for instance one with "Yes" and "No" options. My intention is that when one clicks "Yes", the prompt dialog disappears and also when he clicks "No".I have seen sample bots with the functionality but i just cant figure out how it is implemented.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly you can't minimize the `PromptDialog` items once they are clicked.

But instead you can use `SuggestedActions` which are buttons displayed at the bottom of your window and disappear once they are clicked.

See sample in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

And you can have a look to what it will render here: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/WebChat?f=SuggestedActions&e=example1

Comment: Thank you @Nicolus. Actually I just learnt there is a way i can handle my issue and that is by use of `SuggestedActions` You have any link to implementation tutorials?

Comment: I added the link to the documentation in my post